# PNG image still showing gray and white square border in Website?

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG.  I'm trying to put it on my website but for some reason, it is showing the PNG background, even though the file type is .png.

CSS Code:

```
  .items img{
  border: none;
  background: none;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;


}
```

[image: This is what it is showing on top of a black background.]

This is what it is showing on top of a black background.

The html is just an img tag with the source linking to the png.

Comment: a png image isn't necessarely a transparent image

Comment: PNG *Portable Network Graphics* doesn't always mean pictures with a transparent background. It is a format.only!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a PNG file. 
 You can see it if you open in Photoshop, background is not transparent. 
[image]

If you want your file transparent, let's use Magic Wand to select the selection area you want to clear.

 
[image]